# Unable to use flask.g to access variables in other functions

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use `flask.g` to store variables that can be accessed in other functions, but I don't seem to be doing something correctly.  The application generates the following error when I try to access `g.name`:  `AttributeError: '_RequestGlobals' object has no attribute 'name'`.

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.g) for `flask.g` says:

> Just store on this whatever you want. For example a database
>   connection or the user that is currently logged in.

Here's a complete, minimal example that illustrates the error that I receive when trying to access the variable outside of the function it was created in.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, redirect, url_for, g
from wtforms import Form, TextField

application = app = Flask('wsgi')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name =  form.name.data
        g.name = name

        # Need to create an instance of a class and access that in another route
        #g.api = CustomApi(name)

        return redirect(url_for('get_posts'))

    else:

        return render_template_string(template_form, form=form)

@app.route('/posts', methods=['GET'])
def get_posts():
    # Need to access the instance of CustomApi here
    #api = g.api
    name = g.name
    return render_template_string(name_template, name=name)


class LoginForm(Form):
    name = TextField('Name')

template_form = """
{% block content %}
<h1>Enter your name</h1>

<form method="POST" action="/">
    <div>{{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}</div><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>    
</form>
{% endblock %}

"""

name_template = """
{% block content %}

    <div>"Hello {{ name }}"</div><br>

{% endblock %}

"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to track authentication information, I'd suggest one of the Flask plugins like [Flask-Login](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Login/) or [Flask-Principal](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Principal/).

For example, we use Flask-Principal. It raises the identity-loaded signal when somebody authenticates (or it detects an authentication cookie). We then map their logged-in identity with a user in our database. Something like this:

```
# not actual code
@identity_loaded.connect_via(app)
def on_identity_loaded(sender, identity):
  user = Person.query.filter(Person.username==identity.person.username).one()
  g.user = user
```

and then we can use g.user in any controller or template. (We're actually ripping a lot of this out, it was a easy, lazy hack that's caused more trouble than it's worth.)

If you don't want to use a module, there's a built-in signal you can hook into at the start of every request:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbcon/

```
# This runs before every request
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = your_magic_user_function()
```

and g.user would then be magically available everywhere.

I hope that helps!

Comment: The trouble with using @app.before_request in my case is that I need to get username and passsword information from the user to make use of my magic_user_function().  I'check out the modules that you mentioned.

Comment: Thought I would follow-up to let you know that this was what I ended up doing.  I had to re-write my wrapper to support this method, but it wasn't too bad.  Thanks for the answers on my Flask questions btw Rachel!

Answer (score 20):

The `g` object is a request-based object and does not persist between requests, i.e. `g` is recreated between your request to `index` and your request to `get_posts`.

[Application Globals in Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-globals):

> Flask provides you with a special object that ensures it **is only valid for the active request and that will return different values for each request**. In a nutshell: it does the right thing, like it does for request and session.

For persistent storage of tiny data between requests use [`sessions`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#sessions) instead. You may (but should not) get away with storing the data in the `app` object directly for global (all sessions) application state, similar to what `config` does, if you find a really good reason to do so.

For more complex data use databases.

Comment: I understand your answer for tiny bits of information like simple variables, but how do I create an instance of a class and share that across multiple functions?  Specifically I'm creating an instance of a class that returns authentication information and I'd like to use that returned data in multiple routes.

Comment: Using the `session` to reconstruct your objects across requests would be the easiest way to go. Like store the `user_id`, maybe. Serialization may also work. Pick the method with least overhead and most readability and sense.

Comment: @Raj This should be the accepted answer as it defines why `g.users` didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use sessions in flask. In your case, you just want to save the user/name in your request and the easiest way is to use sessions.

```
from flask import session
app.secret_key = 'some key for session'
```

Then, your functions could be changed as below:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        session['name'] =  form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('get_posts'))
    else:
        return render_template_string(template_form, form=form)

@app.route('/posts', methods=['GET'])
def get_posts():
    if 'name' in session:
        name = session['name']
    else:
        name = "Unknown"
    return render_template_string(name_template, name=name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to shed a bit more light on the use of `g` global in storing data. `g` only stores data for the lifetime of a request and for any subsequent redirections to another route. Afterwards the `g` global is set back to null. This means whatever was set in `g` in one request can't be accessed during another request. Use sessions to store data that will be accessed across requests.

One benefit of using `g` global is when connecting to a database to fetch a user. For example, may be the admin from the database. The admin can be store in the `g` global using the below method.

```
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def text():
    g.a = User.query.filter_by(email='admin@gmail.com')
    

@app.route("/getTrue", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getTrue():
    form = UserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if g.a == form.email.data:
              return "Admin is logged in"
        else:
              return "User is logged in"
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

In the example above, the `g` can be use to save data which will be use in another request. I hope this helps, thanks.